# c# Json.NET deserialize JSON with no keys

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

The response JSON has the following format:

[
`[174854391,1516548168819,0.1011,11841],`
`[174854384,1516548165151,1.05935542,11842],`
`[174854383,1516548165149,0.18174458,11841],` 
`[174854363,1516548161814,0.01,11841]`
]

which can also be represented as follows
[ [ ID, MTS, AMOUNT, PRICE ], [ ID, MTS, AMOUNT, PRICE ], [ ID, MTS, AMOUNT, PRICE ]... ]

When I deserialize the JSON string I need to map each block into a **new object**, for example

```
public class myObject
{
   public long id { get; set; }
   public double mts { get; set; }
   public double amount { get; set; }
   public double price { get; set; }
}
```

so the final result should be

```
List<myObject>
```

I don't have any problem to map a JSON into objects when the string has the **key:value format**, but since I don't have keys here I wonder what is the best way to accomplish the task.

My solution is verbose and it uses regular expressions, which sounds crazy to me because I'm sure this is a very common issue that could be probably solved easily using the right **Json.NET** method.

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: The problem is that [ [174854391,1516548168819,0.1011,11841]... is not a **[valid json](http://json-schema.org/)**

Comment: The keyword to research is `Deserialize`  But you will likely need to write a converter to create those objects